# How to make delay for each box in Autosys?

Tags: autosys

I am having BOX-A which is having BOX-A1, BOX-B1 and BOX-C1. Each boxes are having multiple jobs. Here my doubt is Once I start the BOX-A, first it should trigger BOX-A1 and it should complete all of its jobs and also should wait for 5 min. After the successful completion of BOX-A1 jobs then BOX-B1 should trigger, same way it should trigger all of the jobs and should wait for 5 min then BOX-C1 trigger. Can anyone Pls provide the Jil script for this?

Thanks in Advance 
Sherin Pooja

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if an option is present at Autosys level.

But hoping the jobs are bash scripts.
To the first jobs of both BOX-B1 and BOX-C1 boxes, at the first line or before the actual command add a sleep command

```
sleep 300        # 5 mins in seconds
```

the script would be paused for 5 mins before it begins processing the net lines.

Hope this helps.